# WooCommerce custom function for shipping

Tags: wordpress, plugins, woocommerce

I'm trying to create a custom function for a WooCommerce shipping plugin by wooforce. There are two plugins, ups and usps.

What I'm trying to achieve is if a customer adds a product from category X or any of its sub categories, all rates except for ups ground get unset.

If those products are not present in the cart, all options remain available.

The developers pointed me to this code, but I'm still pretty new to PHP and WordPress/WooCommerce structured PHP so I'm a bit stuck as how to proceed.

Here's the code they gave me.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_package_rates', 'hide_shipping_method_when_shipping_class_product_is_not_in_cart', 10, 2);

function hide_shipping_method_when_shipping_class_product_is_not_in_cart($available_shipping_methods, $package)
{

    // Shipping class IDs that need the method removed

    $shipping_class_ids = array(
        27,
    );
    $shipping_services_to_hide = array(
        'wf_fedex_woocommerce_shipping:FEDEX_GROUND',
                'wf_fedex_woocommerce_shipping:FEDEX_2_DAY_AM' 
    );
    $shipping_class_exists = false;

    foreach(WC()->cart->cart_contents as $key => $values) {
        if (in_array($values['data']->get_shipping_class_id() , $shipping_class_ids)) {
            $shipping_class_exists = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (!$shipping_class_exists) {
        foreach($shipping_services_to_hide as & $value) {
            unset($available_shipping_methods[$value]);
        }
    }

    return $available_shipping_methods;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to figure this out on my own. Here's the code for anyone who may need this function in the future.
This function works specifically with the WooForce Shipping plugins.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_package_rates', 'hide_shipping_method_when_shipping_class_product_is_not_in_cart', 10, 2);
    function hide_shipping_method_when_shipping_class_product_is_not_in_cart($available_shipping_methods, $package){
    // set our flag to be false until we find a product in that category
   $cat_check = false;

    // check each cart item for our category
   foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {

$product = $cart_item['data'];

// replace 'membership' with your category's slug
if ( has_term( 'ammo', 'product_cat', $product->id ) ) {
    $cat_check = true;
    // break because we only need one "true" to matter here
    break;
}
    }

    // if a product in the cart is in our category, do something
   if ( $cat_check ) {
// we have the category, do what we want
    // Shipping class IDs that need the method removed
    $shipping_class_ids = array(
        1,
        2,
        3,
        18,
        23,
        33,
        47,
        49
    );
    $shipping_services_to_hide = array(
        'wf_shipping_usps:D_PRIORITY_MAIL',
                'wf_shipping_usps:D_EXPRESS_MAIL'
    );
    $shipping_class_exists = false;
    foreach(WC()->cart->cart_contents as $key => $values) {
        if (in_array($values['data']->get_shipping_class_id() , $shipping_class_ids)) {
            $shipping_class_exists = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!$shipping_class_exists) {
        foreach($shipping_services_to_hide as & $value) {
            unset($available_shipping_methods[$value]);
        }
    }
    return $available_shipping_methods;
}
else{
    return $available_shipping_methods;
}
    }
```